# How can I play custom alarm(saved in my application bundle as m4r format) obtained from push notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

How can I play custom alarm(saved in my application bundle as m4r format) obtained from push notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't play m4r format sounds. For information on the formats it supports (and how to convert them), see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html).